# How to change image color?

Tags: flutter

How to change the image color?

original image :

[image: original]

expect :

[image: expect]

code :

```
Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 181.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 46.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          colors: [
            Color(0xFFB3E2D6),
            Color(0xFF18A2A5).withOpacity(0.5),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            right: -20,
            bottom: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/border_background.png',
              width: 220,
              height: 220,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: -5,
            bottom: 0,
            top: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/lisa-removebg-preview.png',
              height: 151,
              width: 207,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              color: Color(0xFF7CD2CC), colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

I try to create widgets and change the image color in the widget. but, not identical to the expectation

could you help me to fix some problems with this design?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For this you can use the `ColorFilitered` widget.

## Without ColorFilter

```
Image.network("https://myImage"),
```

### output:

[image]

## With ColorFilter

```
ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter:
          ColorFilter.mode(Colors.teal.withOpacity(0.7), BlendMode.color),
      child: Image.network(
        "https://myUrl",
      ),
    );
```

### output:

[image]

You can change the Color with its opacity as you can see and also the Blendmode, more on Blendmodes [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode.html)